# Is there a drop in technology between Revenge of The Sith and A New Hope, and is it ever explained in-universe?

Tags: star-wars

Whilst watching the ***Star Wars*** movies recently for the first time<sup>**1**</sup> - in order of release - I detected a decrease in the technology between the last of the "new" movies - *Revenge of The Sith* - and the first of the "old" movies - *A New Hope*.

I now have two questions:

1. **Is this apparent drop in technology real or perceived?**
2. If it's real, **is it ever explained in-universe?**<sup>**2**</sup>

---

<sup>**1** Yes, it *has* taken me this long and I'm 28!</sup>

**2** I know that out-of-universe it is because an improvement in the technology, CGI capabilities and imagination and so on between those movies (*ANH* was release in 1977 and *RotS* was released in 2005).

Comment: Basically a dupe of [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/69341/31936), which is marked as a dupe of [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/69341/31936).